# NSLayoutConstraint animation glitch

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nslayoutconstraint, autoresizingmask

I've decided to switch to constraints and face up with animation problems. In `autoresizing mask` world everything works fine. `UIView` is attached to right top. Content inside use `autoresizing mask`.
[image]

Animate code:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut]) {
    self.constraints.first(where: {$0.firstAttribute == .height})?.constant = dstSize.height
    self.constraints.first(where: {$0.firstAttribute == .width})?.constant = dstSize.width
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move constraint's change outside the animation block

```
self.constraints.first(where: {$0.firstAttribute == .height})?.constant = dstSize.height
self.constraints.first(where: {$0.firstAttribute == .width})?.constant = dstSize.width
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut]) { 
    self.superView!.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

## Update

In your Github attached code you need to re-layout the main view  not the container

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: I start with same code. It not worked. Without `setNeedsLayout` it just jump to final state.

Comment: Where do you  perform these constraints inside the view subclass ? also check edit , consider `withDuration: 0.5`

Comment: Added simple project with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- It's good practice to make properties for the constraints you want to update later;
- Only the `layoutIfNeeded` call have to be inside an animation block;
- It looks like `setNeedsLayout` is unnecessary. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: 1) Thanks, I know about it. It just experiment, not final code;
3) Without it no animation at all;

Comment: Pushed simple project with problem [here](https://github.com/AlexandrGraschenkov/LayoutConstraint_Stackoverflow)